# Do lithium and beryllium want to lose electrons to be like helium?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electronic-configuration

I can't seem to remember. I know that they all want to fill their valence shells, but, aren't these different?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, lithium wants to lose electrons to be like helium because **full valence shells are more stable states** and all noble gases have full valence shells. So alkali metals lose one electron to achieve nearest noble gas configuration.

But **beryllium is exceptional because of its small atomic and ionic radii**. Due to this, its **ionization potential is very high**. So it mostly forms covalent bonds.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they do. All alkali metals, in group 1 of the periodic table, display the tendency to lose electrons as well as group 2 alkaline earth metals. Instead of losing one electron like alkali metals, alkaline earth metals such as beryllium lose two!

The loss of an electron to some other element, say a halogen, is very favorable as it gives the potential for alkali metals or alkaline earth metals to form a full valence shell or stable octet.

Therefore it is very common to see ions such as $\ce{H+}$ as well as $\ce{Li^{+}}$ as well as $\ce{Be^{2+}}$. Thus, salts such as $\ce{NaCl}$ as well as other compounds such as hydroxides, $\ce{Li(OH)}$ are the product of these metals once they lose their electrons and react with another element.

First ionization energies:

[image]

Comment: In general this is true. However, Beryllium is *very* special. Like no other (Main group) Metal it will form covalent bonds with non-metalls. This is due to the fact that the electron conformation is $\ce{1s^2 2s^2}$ and hence has already a full shell. The most stable oxidation state is +2 though.

Comment: @Martin although the electron configuration for beryllium is stable and the atmo is quite small, the first and second ionization energies 9.32 eV, 18.21 eV respectively.